# Where does getResourceAsStream(file) search for the file?

Tags: java, class, jvm

I've got confused by `getResourceAsStream()`;

My package structure looks like:

```
\src
|__ net.floodlightcontroller // invoked getResourceAsStream() here
|__ ...
|__ resources
    |__ floodlightdefault.properties //target
    |__ ...
```

And I want to read from floodlightdefault.properties. Here is my code, lying in the `net.floodlightcontroller` package:

```
package net.floodlightcontroller.core.module;
// ...
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                 .getResourceAsStream("floodlightdefault.properties");
```

But it failed, getting `is == null`. So I'm wondering how exactly does `getResourceAsStream(file)` search for the `file`. I mean does it work through certain `PATH`s or in a certain *order*?

If so, how to config the places that `getResourceAsStream()` looks for?

Thx!

Comment: Do you have added the resources directory in a classpath when running your code? Generally speaking, the behavior of getResourceAsStream depends on the ClassLoader implementation.

Comment: Generally speaking it will also depend on what `this` refers to.

Comment: To fix your null problem, there are two things I see initially. First, it looks like you just need to change your directory to `"resources/floodlightdefault.properties"`. Second, the method could be looking for the resource inside your build directory and the directory structure you've shown appears to be the IDE project's source folder. Though of course if you've added the resources to the project, the IDE ought to copy the files to the build directory automatically. In a quick test with Netbeans, my resources only come up null if I remove them from _both_ the build and the src folder.

Comment: How are you building your project? Where does floodlightdefault.properties end up at run time?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you call `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(File)`, Java looks for the file in the same directory as the class indicated by `this`.  So if your file structure is:

```
\src
|__ net.floodlightcontroller.core.module
    |__ Foo.java
|__ ...
|__ resources
    |__ floodlightdefault.properties //target
    |__ ...
```

Then you'll want to call:

```
InputStream is = Foo.class.getClassLoader()
             .getResourceAsStream("..\..\..\resources\floodlightdefault.properties");
```

Better yet, change your package structure to look like:

```
\src
|__ net.floodlightcontroller.core.module
    |__ Foo.java
    |__ floodlightdefault.properties //target
    |__ ...
```

And just call:

```
InputStream is = Foo.class.getClassLoader()
             .getResourceAsStream("floodlightdefault.properties");
```

Comment: @Jones Thanks, and I added `resources` to the class path, it works also.

Comment: didn't work for me. My file was only found when placed in the /resources which is parallel to /src