# Java is giving me errors when trying to load an image through a file path

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource, imageicon

I'm trying to load an image using ImageIcon and Java keeps giving a NullPointerException on this line no matter how I format the file path:

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/img/icons/options.gif"));
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the structure of the project?

Comment: Well presumably it can't find that resource. Unfortunately you haven't given us any information about how you expect it to find the resource. Where is it? Is the class in a jar file?

Comment: The source files are located in a folder called SimpleGame and in that folder is /img/icons/options.gif

Comment: Could this be of use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570608/where-does-getresourceasstreamfile-search-for-the-file/19627038

Comment: Have you tried `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource...`?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading slash from your path of the image in `getResouce` call

```
getResource("img/icons/options.gif")
```

Path to image is relative to "your class.java"

Answer (score 0):

In your NullPointerException error stack trace it would have given you the line number. In that line some value could be null hence this error. Try to check each value. You could debug using eclipse, or try to print the value using System.out.println and check.  The reason could be in some other line which you have not given.