# Where does this.getClass().getResource() look?

Tags: java, url

Say I call `this.getClass().getResource()` in some class in order to obtain a URL of a file.

Where does `getResource()` start looking? In the main `src` folder of the project? In the main package folder? What is the 'root folder' for the `getResource()` method?

I was always confused by this method, would be great if someone explained this.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570608/where-does-getresourceasstreamfile-search-for-the-file

Comment: You should really look into the [method's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) as well into all the other SO questions dealing with the same topic.

Comment: Reminder: the end user only has a bunch of jars, which constitute the classpath of the application. He doesn't have any project, and he doesn't have any `src` directory. Don't confuse your development environment with the runtime environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class.getResource()` finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader of the class.

Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:

If the name begins with a `'/' ('\u002f')`, then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:

```
modified_package_name/name
```

Where the `modified_package_name` is the package name of this object with `'/'` substituted for `'.' ('\u002e')`.

The `ClassLoader` class uses a delegation model to search for classes and resources. Each instance of `ClassLoader` has an associated parent class loader. When requested to find a class or resource, a `ClassLoader` instance will delegate the search for the class or resource to its parent class loader before attempting to find the class or resource itself. The virtual machine's built-in class loader, called the "bootstrap class loader", does not itself have a parent but may serve as the parent of a `ClassLoader` instance.

The more you [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html), the more you learn :)